# Converting methanol into methane

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, hydrocarbons

I know that methane to methanol is a common practice, but is it possible to convert methanol back into methane, and would it be a relatively easy process to achieve?

Answer (score 5):

[Methanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methanation) is a process whereby synthesis gas is converted to methane.

$\ce{CO + 3H2 -> CH4 + H2O}$

Methanol, like nearly all organic molecules, can be [gasified](http://www.netl.doe.gov/research/coal/energy-systems/gasification/gasifipedia/gasification-chemistry) to form synthesis gas at elevated temperatures.

$$\ce{CH3OH -> CO + 2 H2}$$

(Note: the gasification reaction is actually a complex balance of many types of reactions.  Often times mixtures of $\ce{CO}$, $\ce{H2}$, $\ce{H2O}$, and $\ce{CO2}$ are obtained.  The reaction above is the ideal case where complete conversion is achieved.)

Thus a process for converting methanol to methane could proceed via gasification followed by methanation.

However, since methanol is made commercially from methane by essentially the reverse process, this route is unlikely to be economically viable!

Comment: You wrote that this is unlikely to be financially profitable (economically viable). However, it could be very ecological or environmentally friendly. A farmer could produce methanol by fermenting wood chips or other organic material. After distillation, gasification, and methanation, the resulting methane gas could be used to heat the farmer's home in winter. The combustion of methane gas in the presence of oxygen does not form black particulates (Soot and smoke). Air pollution would be minimal. Burning fossil fuels moves solid carbon underground into the air.

Comment: Continuing from my earlier comment, growing corn, or trees, and fermenting corn or wood pulp would pull some carbon out of the air, store the carbon in the corn or wood pulp, and then put than carbon back into the air when the methane gas is burned ina furnace to heat a home in winter. Some carbon in corn comes from the soil, but less than 100% of carbon in corn comes from the soil. When we burn fossil fuels, 100% of the carbon come from underground. We don't want to move carbon from underground into the atmosphere too quickly. The greenhouse effect would cause some plants to die.

Comment: Human use plants to filter air, water, and as a source of food. Destabilizing the climate and weather patterns by moving large amounts of carbon from underground into the atmosphere is inadvisable. Perhaps we can ferment food crops into methanol and ethanol. After gasification, the methan or Ethan or other hydrocarbons can be used in older traditional natural gas burning furnaces to heat a person's home in winter. The alchohils need not be transported in tanker trucks which burn diesel fuel if you own a small farm. Alchohol can be produced by fermentation at the same site as where it is burned

Comment: That's all true.  But it's worth noting that the partial oxidation of methane, that is, converting methane to methanol, has been a "holy grail" of chemical engineering for many decades.  That is, an oxidative, (comparatively) low-temperature, low-pressure process to achieve $\ce{CH4 + 1/2 O2 -> CH3OH}$ efficiently & economically, has been a goal of industrial chemistry for a long, long time.  That's because methanol is easy to transport and store, and people are willing to pay more for that.  And because natural gas is very, very cheap.  So methanol -> methane isn't likely to be practical...

Answer (score 4):

Some methanogenic miroorganisms isolated from human feces are known to digest $\ce{H2}$ and $\ce{CH3OH}$ to produce $\ce{CH4}$.